# Hot to find values of related tables from a pivot table in resources with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to retrieve the name of the users and the name of the tasks from a resource that represents a pivot table that is `task_user`.
However I would like to do that using the resources of Laravel.

This is the code in **TaskUserResource**:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'task_id' => $this->task_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'task_name' => Task::where('id', $this->task_id)->pluck('name')->first(), //to edit
        'user_name' => User::where('id', $this->user_id)->pluck('name')->first(), //to edit
    ];
}
```

The code works correctly. By the way I am asking myself if is it a way to do it better because I think it's expensive doing two queries with eloquent every returning row of the table `task_user`.
The tables `users` and `tasks` have a many to many relationship.

**User.php**:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Task.php**:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

This is my controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();

        $tasks = Task::all();

        $tasks_users = TaskUserResource::collection(TaskUser::all()); //this is the query

        $users = UserResource::collection(User::all()); 

        return view('home')->with(['task_user'=>json_encode($tasks_users), 'tasks'=>$tasks, 'projects'=>$projects, 'users'=>json_encode($users)]);
    }
}
```

Can help?

Comment: Can you show the actual query for `TaskUserResource` to fetch data, also its better if you can perform eager loading while you are fetching data from its related models instead of adding your logic in `toArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `user()` and `task()` `belongsTo()` relations in TaskUser pivot model.

**TaskUser:**

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

When load this relations with `with()` method.

**Controller:**

```
$tasks_users = TaskUser::with(['user', 'task'])->get();
$tasks_users = TaskUserResource::collection(tasks_users);
```

Then replace code in resource.

**TaskUserResource:**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'task_id' => $this->task_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'task_name' => $this->task->name,
        'user_name' => $this->user->name,
    ];
}
```